# How to index odd number words using shingle in elasticsearch

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch, lucene

I have a field named "title_search" having value "apple iphone 6s".I am using shingle type to index the data field.Below are the mapping and setting.

### Setting

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "bigram_combiner": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "custom_shingle",
                        "my_char_filter"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "custom_shingle": {
                    "type": "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2,
                    "max_shingle_size": 3,
                    "output_unigrams": true
                },
                "my_char_filter": {
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": " ",
                    "replacement": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Mapping

```
{
    "products": {
        "properties": {
            "title_search" : {
                  "type" : "string",
                  "analyzer":"bigram_combiner"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I analyze the field it is giving me the following result.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "apple",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "appleiphone",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 0,
      "positionLength": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "appleiphone6s",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 0,
      "positionLength": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "iphone",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "iphone6s",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "shingle",
      "position": 1,
      "positionLength": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "6s",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

It is giving some results.But if user searches for **apple6s** ,It is not giving any result. Is there any changes in settings, so that apple6s will be also index using shingle type.

Comment: The shingle token filter cannot "reorder" the tokens, so in "apple iphone 6s", there's no way that you can have "6s" come before "iphone" in that stream. However, one path you can investigate is to use synonyms so that "apple" gets expanded to "apple iphone". So if someone types "apple 6s", it gets expanded to "apple iphone 6s" which you have indexed.

Comment: I don't understand why you're removing space characters, though.

Comment: Suppose field having value "apple iphone 6s" , If user searches for "iphone6s"(wihtout space) and "iphone 6s"(with space), the result should come. But the real problem is if user searches for "apple6s", it is not giving result.Any help?

Comment: See my first comment

Comment: But this is some type of temp fix and how can we add so much data in synonyms? Is there any better solution?

Comment: This is why it is not a good idea to remove the spaces. If you indexed your data with spaces (i.e. "apple iphone 6s"), then the user would be able to find "apple 6s" because the terms `apple` and `6s` would match, but if you remove the spaces it is not possible anymore